# How to print JSON element having comma in key?

Tags: node.js

Here, I have a JSON object like

```
var Obj = { id: 'xx', 'xlink:href': 'http://www.example.com' }
```

Now, I can print **id** by

```
console.log(Obj.id);
```

But I am not able to get url by doing like this,

```
console.log(Obj.xlink:href);
```

It gives me error like,

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Question is here, How can I print data of a key, having *comma* in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said in their answer, you should try following

```
console.log(Obj['xlink:href']);
```

Comment: Yup. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use bracket notation

```
Obj["xlink:href"]
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 3):

The dot notation in JavaScript is only useful when the key is suitable as a token.
Otherwise, you should use the bracket notation.

Here, `Obj['xlink:href']` will return the value you want.